# how to make an infinite autoplay slider on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a slider that should automatically rotate and the problem is that when rotating, the photos that have been or will be shown remain in the background. Also, in the background there should be one photo on the left and right, and not 2 as I did.

I tried many times to change the code in JavaScript, as well as CSS, but nothing changed and left the original code. I will be very glad for your help.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setInterval(rotate, 2000);
});

function rotate() {
  var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
  var lastChild = slider.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  slider.lastElementChild.remove();
  slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', lastChild);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.6, 0.32, 1.6);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.box:nth-child(7),
.box:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(0.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box:nth-child(2),
.box:nth-child(6) {
  transform: scale(0.4) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box:nth-child(3),
.box:nth-child(5) {
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  left: -13%;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  left: -5%;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  left: 10%;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  left: 50%;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  left: 71%;
}

.box:nth-child(6) {
  left: 85%;
}

.box:nth-child(7) {
  left: 100%;
}

@keyframes firstChild {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: scale(0.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    left: -13%;
    transform: scale(0.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?a')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?b')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?c')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?d')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?e')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?f')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?g')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?h')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?i')"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?j')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if there was a live version we could look at.  Is this on the web somewhere?  Or could you put it up somewhere for us to look at?

Comment: I can leave a link to a mockup that shows how it should work. To watch, you need to click on the review button in the upper right corner. https://framer.com/projects/Product-Hub-copy--8r05VozbZTVQDouB2Idb

Comment: If you just post a screenshot of the slider in the mockup, that is very valuable information.  It totally changes the solution.  You only need to show three slides at a time, correct?

Comment: Yes, I can add a screenshots as a links only. This is what it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNar3.png. And this is  what it looks like in my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWlLb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines of CSS:

First, hide all the boxes:

```
.box {
  display:none
}
```

Next, show only the ones that you need to be visible:

```
.box:nth-child(2), .box:nth-child(3), .box:nth-child(4),
.box:nth-child(5), .box:nth-child(6) {
  display:block;
}
```

I know you think that you only need two in the background, but you actually do need two on each side, as these are the positions that the left and right slides slide from and to.  You'll just display the slider in a space where the far left and far right slides won't be visible.

Comment: Everything works as it should, I am very grateful for your help!!